# why is $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Im trying to understand how the equation below was generated. A step-by-step solution would be awesome.
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Just cross multiply.

Comment: Rationalize the denominator.

Comment: Alternatively, just multiply

$$\left( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \right) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$$ and remember the formula $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes for this question. It doesn't feel like homework.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have adjusted the score..it is a new year :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2.$

Put $\ a = \sqrt{n+1},\quad b = \sqrt{n}\ .$

$\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right) = \left(\sqrt{n+1}\right)^2 - \left(\sqrt{n}\right)^2 = n+1 - n =1.$

Therefore, starting with the RHS and rationalising the denominator,

\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \times 1\\
\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \times \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\\
\\
= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)}\\
\\
= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1}\\
\\
= \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\ .\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the downvote...

Comment: your solution made it clear. Thank's!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$\frac{1}{x}$$ means something so that, when you multiply it by $x$, you get $1$.  So check that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is, indeed, something so  that, when you multiply it by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$, you get $1$.